# Can not export folder from project to jar using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jar

I've got the following project structure:

```
-Project name

--src

--web-content
```

If I export my project as "Runnable JAR file", no 'web-content' folder will be in exported archive. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the **Save as ANT script** in export wizard.
Editing the ANT script, then run it to produce the archive that you want.

```
<project default="create_run_jar">
<target name="create_run_jar">
    <jar destfile="my_run.jar">
        <fileset dir="x:/workspace/Project name/bin"/><!-- Default output folder of your Java project -->
        <fileset dir="x:/workspace/Project name/web-content"/><!-- add extra folder-->
    </jar>
</target>
</project>
```